# What the differences between these lisp-macro writing styles?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm reading the common lisp book and using three writing style to write the macro. But something different between these.

```
(defmacro test_var (var)
  (list 'format 't var))

(defmacro test_var2 (var)
  `(format t ,var))

(defmacro test_var3 (var)
  '(format t)
  var)
```

and I test these three macro:

```
CL-USER> (test_var "ss")
ss
NIL

CL-USER> (test_var2 "ss")
ss
NIL

CL-USER> (test_var3 "ss")
ss

CL-USER>
```

Why dose the third "NIL" disappeare? What's happen??

FYI: What if I find something interesting about macro next time, how could I find how it works details?

Comment: what is test_var3 supposed to do?

Comment: Examples in book only show the grammar which included test_var and test_var2. I writing test_var3 to test whether it work or not. Then I find this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 are *not* equivalent. Use [macroexpand-1](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) to see what your call expands to:

```
? (macroexpand-1 '(test_var "ss"))
(FORMAT T "ss")
T

? (macroexpand-1 '(test_var2 "ss"))
(FORMAT T "ss")
T

? (macroexpand-1 '(test_var3 "ss"))
"ss"
T
```

So `(test_var "ss")` and `(test_var2 "ss")` are translated to `(format t "ss")` at compile time. At execution time, , the call to `format` prints the argument as a side effect and the REPL prints `NIL` which is the value the expression (i.e. what `format`) returns.

But `(test_var3 "ss")` is simply translated to `"ss"` which evaluated to itself. There's no side effect here and the REPL prints this value.

Comment: That's means the macro `test_var3` looks like the function that return the last line.

Comment: Look in your book again. I'm quite sure that you made a mistake when you copied `test_var3`.